# How to post rating in Google Places

Tags: google-places-api

I have a task that users have to login with Google Auth and then their ratings to go on Google Places as raitings.
How can i put their ratings on Google Places for the current site (www.site.com) as raitings?
What is heeded for the aim?

I read the google places api and i tried this https://www.google.bg/search?newwindow=1&es_sm=93&q=google+places+api+post+rating&oq=google+places+api+post+rating&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30.89333.90856.0.91251.2.2.0.0.0.0.133.242.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.1.109.ABadz49XXUo

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the prblem for my case.
When i login the user with Google login, i grab the profile info and than the user is redirected to this place that i want. This happend by copy and paste the url from Google Maps for this place.

**Important:**
After hours of reading you should know that Google Places API is only for reading, Google Maps embded is forbidden by the header of their response. That means that you can't use this url in iframe for example.